# Undefined references and gcc error when building Haskell executable with cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix, cabal-install

I set up a simple cabal project to try and acquaint myself with it better, and I have a very simple Main.hs file:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

So then I try to build it, using `cabal new-configure` and then `cabal new-build`. There's no problems for the configure command, but building it gives this:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, /home/redacted/Documents/Haskell/nixtut/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/newp-0.1.0.0/x/newp/build/newp/newp-tmp/Main.o )
Linking /home/daniel/Documents/Haskell/nixtut/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/newp-0.1.0.0/x/newp/build/newp/newp ...
/nix/store/6yjpyqkx6d9k5f2s2g8h9kz40q6rz1yx-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: //nix/store/siks2gcfwx6qwh27m7c5r5lixcr621bd-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `_IO_enable_locks@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/nix/store/6yjpyqkx6d9k5f2s2g8h9kz40q6rz1yx-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: //nix/store/siks2gcfwx6qwh27m7c5r5lixcr621bd-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__mmap@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/nix/store/6yjpyqkx6d9k5f2s2g8h9kz40q6rz1yx-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: //nix/store/siks2gcfwx6qwh27m7c5r5lixcr621bd-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__munmap@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/nix/store/6yjpyqkx6d9k5f2s2g8h9kz40q6rz1yx-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: //nix/store/siks2gcfwx6qwh27m7c5r5lixcr621bd-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__mprotect@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/nix/store/6yjpyqkx6d9k5f2s2g8h9kz40q6rz1yx-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: //nix/store/siks2gcfwx6qwh27m7c5r5lixcr621bd-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__tunable_get_val@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/nix/store/6yjpyqkx6d9k5f2s2g8h9kz40q6rz1yx-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: //nix/store/siks2gcfwx6qwh27m7c5r5lixcr621bd-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__sigtimedwait@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

Here is my .cabal file:

```
name:                newp
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            toying around
-- description:
homepage:            none
-- bug-reports:
license:             BSD-3-Clause
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              redacted
maintainer:          none
-- copyright:
category:            practice
extra-source-files:  CHANGELOG.md

executable newp
  main-is:             Main.hs
  --other-modules:
  -- other-extensions:
  build-depends:       base ^>=4.9.0.0
  -- hs-source-dirs:
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I can't seem to understand what's wrong. GCC is installed, I'm not trying to link any external library, I'm not using any other modules, I have no idea know what these references allude to.

Any help is appreciated, because frankly, I don't know where to begin with this. I've tried looking online, but all the situations are different and the solutions don't seem to apply to me. I noticed that for others a similar error occurs when there's an issue with linking or not including modules in the cabal file, but I'm not sure how or if that applies here.

Comment: Did you try to see if `cabal new-build -v` gives more information?

Comment: This looks like an installation issue of your Nix build-environment; Does `ghc --make Main.hs` work?

Comment: @hvr ghc could compile, but you were probably right that it was a problem with the nix installation. After reinstalling nix the project could build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have a definitive answer as to why the error occurred, after reinstalling nix I could finally build the project. So the issue was not with cabal.